# Embedding Microsoft Word in a browser window (cross-browser)

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

**Background**

Our web application stores Microsoft Word documents which users want to edit (ideally with Word) in their browser of choice.

To access the web application (and the documents), users must login. As they are unwilling to login whenever they edit a document, document retrieval and storage must occur in their login session, which is easiest to accomplish if document download and upload is done by the browser.

**Question**

How can I embed Word into (or at least invoke it from) a browser window to edit a document the browser has retrieved from the server? It should work in both Internet Explorer and Firefox.

**Own Research**

- ActiveX is not supported by Firefox.
- There is not javascript api for invoking (let alone embed) native applications. Even if there were, I don't see how I could pass the document, and neither Internet Explorer 10 not Firefox 20 appears to offer an api to write a file to disk.
- I could write a (signed) Java Applet to invoke Word, but ensuring that all changes are uploaded to the server appears difficult (what if the user closes the browser window before saving in Word?)
- Eclipse has this nice feature of permitting in place editing word documents. This appears to be part of their SWT toolkit, but as that requires native code, I am not sure how to deploy it is an applet?

Comment: If markup isn't *that* important, you could upload to Google docs and embed that. Or convert to odt and use an editor for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if they are embeddable for free, but you can take a look at [Microsoft Office Webapps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-US/web-apps/)

Comment: Also came here to say this

Comment: The documents being edited being confidential, uploading them to a server under the control of a different organization is unlikely to fly (Microsoft Office Webapps would require that, right?). Still, I might propose this if I don't find a more direct solution.